# Write multiple PDF object in one file using magick in R

Tags: r, imagemagick, data-science

I am working to stick two PNGs side by side and then convert the concatenated object to a PDF using the code below. Now how can I write all the PDF objects as pages in a single file? I tried to save all the objects in a list and then pass the list to image_write(), but it did not work.

```
library(magick)
vec_out <- list()
for(i in 1:length(all_stims)){
        stim <- all_stims[i]
        img1 <- image_read(file.path(figures_folder, "across_cluster_heatmaps", paste0("bendall_",stim,".png")))
        img2 <- image_read(file.path(figures_folder, "across_cluster_heatmaps", paste0("farmer_", stim,".png")))
        imgs <- c(img1, img2)
        imgs <- image_append(imgs)
        imgs_pdf <- image_convert(imgs)
        vec_out[[i]] <- imgs_pdf
}

image_write(vec_out, path = file.path(figures_folder, "test.pdf"), format = "pdf")
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you write a knitr-document instead, or as rmarkdown-file?
I could not run your code, since it's not reproducible.

A mini example in rmarkdown:
The following code produces 3 plots in a for-loop.
By choosing `result = 'asis'` as option and by inserting
`cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n")` in the for-loop, every output is printed on a separate page.

````
---
title: "Test page break between two figures"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:3) {
  print(plot(1:i, rnorm(i)))
  cat("\n\n\\pagebreak\n")
}
```
````

I suggest doing something as mentioned above, instead of creating in a first step all pdf-files separately and glue them together in a second step.